# How to plot a scatter plot (month vs area)

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter

I have the data below and am trying to plot a scatter plot for `Month` VS `Area`.

```
Month   Area
feb 13.05
oct 13.7
mar 13.99
sep 14.57
aug 15.45
sep 17.2
sep 19.23
sep 23.41
oct 24.23
aug 26
sep 26.13
mar 27.35
```

When I plot the scatter plot, the plot is something like the attached image. what I am trying to do is to plot the x axis in chronological order (Jan-December) in order. I tried using ggplot2, but I was not able to do so.

[Area VS Month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCEa4.png)

Comment: i guess i didnt post the data correctly. it is something like.Month Area
feb 13.05;
oct 13.7;
mar 13.99;
sep 14.57;
aug 15.45;
sep 17.2;
sep 19.23;
sep 23.41;
oct 24.23;
aug 26;
sep 26.13;
mar 27.35;

Comment: There are editing tools available in the editor - we use Markdown here, and there is a preview window to ensure your post is OK before you submit it. Would you also explain why ggplot2 did not satisfy your needs? Readers generally like to see an attempt here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R does not automatically know what type of data you are giving it. "feb" is not different from "the" as far as the system knows, so if you want something special (like dates) you need to tell the system to do that.

For example:

```
monthData$cleanMonth <-
  as.Date(paste0("2016-",monthData$Month,"-01")
          , format = "%Y-%b-%d")

ggplot(monthData
       , aes(x = cleanMonth
             , y = Area)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month"
               , date_labels = "%b")
```

[image]